# slow startup of event viewer on windows 7 but fast on server 2008

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, event-log, event-viewer

Since switching to Windows 7 for my desktop I've started to get really p***ed off at the length of time it takes to start the event viewer to display the application event log (typically 20-30 secs or disk griding - presumably to load and cache all the events)

I've just noticed that on server 2008 R2 it seems instantaneous.

Is my experience typical? Is there any setting I can tweak to make it fast on Windows 7 as well?

Tim

Answer (score 6):

The Eventvwr.msc from Windows XP runs just fine on Windows 7 and is extremely fast and has a simple and clean view. Just rename it to something else like ClassicEventVwr.msc and put it in system32.

Comment: Related question and answer: http://serverfault.com/a/508483/207165

Answer (score 1):

I have no such problem but loading the application log takes a few (5-ish first time) seconds - but it does the same on idle 2008 R2 servers to me... subsequent launches are almost immediate on both platforms... but it sure is a bit of a resource hog these days, like most newer management consoles from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

hmm, that could be the answer. I'm rebooting my PC and logging on/off etc a lot more often than the server, so it could be the delay only happens the first time.